# RegEx for matching "A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _" and "."

Tags: regex

I need a regex which will allow only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, the _ character, and dot (.) in the input.

I tried:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_.]
```

But, it did not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could do with a bit more info on this one, its a bit vague. Some sample input would be good and the context you are using it, language too?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$
```

From beginning until the end of the string, match one or more of these characters.

*Edit:*

Note that `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of a *line*. When multiline is enabled, this can mean that one line matches, but not the complete string.

Use `\A` for the beginning of the string, and `\z` for the end.

See for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can also be `^[\w.]+$`, thought that doesn't work everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Working from what you've given I'll assume you want to check that someone has NOT entered any letters other than the ones you've listed. For that to work you want to search for any characters other than those listed:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9_.]
```

And use that in a match in your code, something like:

```
if ( /[^A-Za-z0-9_.]/.match( your_input_string ) ) {
   alert( "you have entered invalid data" );
}
```

Hows that?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `^[\w.]+` to match A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to specify more exactly what didn't work and in what environment you are.

As to the claim that the dot is special in a charackter class, this is not true in every programming environment. For example the following perl script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = '!!!.###';
$str =~ s/[A-Za-z_.]/X/g;
print "$str\n";
```

produces

```
!!!X###
```

Answer (score 0):

regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]$/i

This works

Comment: Hello Prem Sai, could you explain in your answer why this works? This would be easier for other people to understand too.

Comment: That's the easiest way to validate the expression which i have been using from the start of my season with this lang. Moreover, you can check this in sails js official website/doc. also https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations

Answer (score 0):

For me, i was looking for a regex like Gmail has, should allow a-z, A-z, 0-9, _, . only here is the Yup format for it i used:

```
Email: Yup.string()
      .email("Please Provide Valid Email")
      .matches(
        /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(.\w{2,3})+$/,
        "Only a-z A-Z _ . 0-9 are allowed in this Field"
       )
```