# Error reading XML with line break into Dataset C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, regex, excel

I had posted a similar error previously [Similar Error Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987524/error-reading-excel-cell-with-line-break-into-dataset?noredirect=1#comment40695320_25987524). But this time for a different program, I have to convert the excel to a XML first and then read the XML into a c# program.

My excel contains line breaks within a cell:

[image]

Now when i convert this into XML using a VB macro file, the XML also contains these line breaks.

[image]

Finally, when i try to read this XML, i am having a line break (\n) escape sequence with this column.

[image]

**Main Problem:**

1. Why is this scenario happening? Note that, line break (\n) is only the escape sequence we can enter in a excel cell (Alt + enter).
2. My input column only contains {a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ }. Any other character should be flagged. I tried to using this Regex:**^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$** from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721602/regex-match-a-z-a-z-0-9-and). But no luck. The problem is, the compiler interprets \n as a line break and not as a character to flag it invalid in my case.

Any suggestions in Regex and this scenario of allowing only {a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[^A-Za-z0-9_]+` with an empty string